# search for `target_item` in `items`; return the array index

Tags: ruby, arrays, while-loop

Can someone help me understand the code below? I have been trying to add 'puts' to see what it does but keep getting errors. This is a code from an exercise/example I was supposed to already know, yet I have no idea what it is doing. It seems to me that I should have an items array defined before the method for this to make sense, but even then I wasn't able to make sense of it.

```
# search for `target_item` in `items`; return the array index
# where it first occurs
def find_item(items, target_item)
  i = 0
  while i < items.count
    current_item = items[i]
    if current_item == target_item
      # found item; return its index; stop here and exit the
      # method
      return i
    end
    i += 1
  end

  # return nil to mean item not found
  nil
end
```

Comment: Damn, okay I just got it! I was utterly confused, this is pretty advanced for me. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about needing an array `items` to run your code.  You will also need a value for the variable `target_item`.  These two variables are passed as *arguments* to the method `find_item`.  If the method finds the value of `target_item` in the array `items` it will return the index of that item in the array (0 for the first element, 1 for the second, and so on.); if it does not, it will return `nil`.

If you run your code in IRB, it will return `=> :find_item`.  That means it found no errors.  That does not mean there are no errors, however, as error can surface when the code is run.

Let's try it with some data.  After running the code defining the method (in IRB), run these three lines:

```
items = ['dog', 'cat', 'pig']
target_item = 'cat'
find_item(items, target_item) #=> 1
```

where `#=> 1` means that the method returned `1`, meaning that it found `target_items` at offset `1` in `items`, which is what we would expect.

This is equivalent to:

```
find_item(['dog', 'cat', 'pig'], 'cat')
```

On the other hand,

```
find_item(items, 'bird') #=> nil
```

as the array does not contain `'bird'`. The two lines

```
current_item = items[i]
if current_item == target_item
```

can be combined into one:

```
if items[i] == target_item
```

but that's beside the point, because Rubiests would not write the method this way.  Instead, you would commonly do it like this:

```
def find_item(items, target_item)
  items.each_with_index { |e,i| return i if e == target_item }
  nil
end
```

[Edit: @Mark has correctly pointed out a much simpler way of writing the method. I will stick with this version, however, as I think you will learn something useful by seeing how it works.]

The built-in Ruby method `each_with_index` is from the `Enumgerable` module, which is always available to you (along with 60+ other method defined in that module).  When you reference a method, it's best to include the class or module in which it was defined.  This method is [Enumerable#each_with_index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index).  Among other things, its easier to find documentation for the method if you know the class or module its from.

Although `each_with_index` was defined in the Enumerable module, it is an "enumerator", meaning that it feeds the values from `items` to the following block, denoted by `{...}` (as here) or `do ... end`.

Run this in IRB:

```
items = ['dog', 'cat', 'pig']
target_item = 'cat'
enum = items.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["dog", "cat", "pig"]:each_with_index>
```

You can convert this to an array to see what it will feed the block:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [["dog", 0], ["cat", 1], ["pig", 2]]
```

Consider now the first element the enumerator will be passed to the block:

```
["dog", 0]
```

The block variables, `e` and `i` in

```
  items.each_with_index { |e,i| return i if e == target_item }
```

will therefore be set equal to:

```
e => "dog"
i => 0
```

Therefore, `e == target_item` becomes `"dog" == "cat"`, which is `false`, so `return 0` is not executed.  For the next items, however,

```
e => "cat"
i => 1
```

As `"cat" == "cat"` is `true`, `return 1` is executed, and we are finished.  If `items` did not contain `cat`, the enumerator would enumerate all items and control would go to the following statement, `nil`.  As that is the last statement executed, the method would return `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

This code appears to be a poorly rewritten `Array#index`. This is identical:

```
items.index(target_item)
```